# Setting hook starts infinite loop and app hangs

Tags: reactjs

This could be related to my problem, but I tried using the answer with no luck. It is like my react component start an infinite loop (the app hangs) when setting the hook setShow(!show):

There is a sandbox here were the problem is shown:
https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-gmqpp

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const CrawlJobs = () => {
  const [mediaList, setMediaList] = useState([]);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMediaData = async () => {
      try {
        setMediaList([{ id: 1, name: "Facebook" }, { id: 2, name: "Twitter" }]);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    fetchMediaData();
  }, [mediaList]);

  const toggle = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {mediaList.map(media => (
        <div>
          <div onClick={() => toggle()}>Show</div>
          {show && <h1>Toggled context</h1>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrawlJobs;
```

Comment: Also, why have you got it as async function on the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: As @Praveen said, Just remove the dependencies from `useEffect` by passing an empty array, `mediaList` is not needed at this context. Also, why the `async function`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this hook, you're updating `mediaList` and watching for changes on the same too.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMediaData = async () => {
      try {
        setMediaList([{ id: 1, name: "Facebook" }, { id: 2, name: "Twitter" }]);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    fetchMediaData();
  }, [mediaList]);
```

That's the cause of the infinite loop. Please use a callback using `useCallback` or completely remove the dependency array there.

Comment: You mean to remove dependency  array or pass empty array as dependancy?

Comment: Can you show an example on exactly what to day? Maybe update the sandbox I provided. I am very new to REACT so not sure what you mean.

Comment: Got it. Removed mediaList from the listener.

Comment: @ThomasSegato Excellent... Great. Happy that it worked.